# Inflating a View inside DialogFragment's onCreateView() causes a memory leak

Tags: android, listview, view, memory-leaks, android-dialogfragment

I have a memory leak in my program. I have a `ListView`, each of its items has a `Button`, when user presses it, I want my program to show a `DialogFragment` with some `EditText` fields and a `Button` which would perform some action with the data from these fields and from the item that started the dialog. So, every time I open and close that dialog, my app's memory consumption increases and after many reopenings it reaches ~150 MB of RAM and then the app freezes (no `OOM` error or crash, just a freeze and slow down of the whole OS showing just a couple of MB of free RAM).

After some testing, I have discovered that the leak is caused, for some reason, by this line `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_flag_dialog, container, false);` (I have marked this in the code with a comment). If I "comment" this line, the leak is gone, RAM consumption of my app isn't increasing anymore after reopening. So, I would like you to help me find the problem why this line (or maybe something else) is causing a memory leak, because my knowledge isn't enough to find a clear clarification and a solution of this problem. The `View` should be garbage collected after I close the dialog, but, for some reason, it isn't.

Below is my code and, by the way, I instantiate and use the `BaseAdapter` provided below with the following code `PopupListAdapter pListAdapter = new PopupListAdapter(getActivity(), someArrayList, someString); listView.setAdapter(pListAdapter);` from another `Fragment` which is inside my `Activity` and which holds the `ListView`. Please don't pay attention to the class name `PopupListAdapter`. I don't use it in a popup window in this case, I use it in a normal `Activity`, I just designed it to be used in a popup window elsewhere and reused it here because it perfectly matches the situation.

```
public class PopupListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    private static final String KEY_COMMENT = "comment";
    private static final String KEY_COMMENT_ID = "id";
    private final DialogFragment dFrag;

    public PopupListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataArg, String number) {
        data = dataArg;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.context = context;
        dFrag = FlagDialogFragment.newInstance("test", number);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popuplistitem, null);

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        TextView comment = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.comment);

        HashMap<String, String> element = new HashMap<String, String>();
        element = data.get(position);

        name.setText(element.get(KEY_NAME));
        date.setText(element.get(KEY_DATE));
        comment.setText(element.get(KEY_COMMENT));

        final Button flagButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.flag_button);
        flagButton.setTag(element.get(KEY_COMMENT_ID));

        flagButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(Utils.TAG, "Comment's ID is " + flagButton.getTag());

                dFrag.show(((ActionBarActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager(), "flag_dialog");
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public static class FlagDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        private String commentId;
        private String number;

        public static FlagDialogFragment newInstance(String listItemTag, String number) {
            FlagDialogFragment f = new FlagDialogFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("comment_id", listItemTag);
            args.putString("number", number);
            f.setArguments(args);

            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            commentId = getArguments().getString("comment_id");
            number = getArguments().getString("number");
            setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            Log.i(Utils.TAG, "FlagDialogFragment's onCreateView() is called");

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_flag_dialog, container, false);// Something in this line is causing a memory leak!!!

            TextView flagNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.flag_number);
            flagNumber.setText(number);

            Button flagButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.flag_button);
            flagButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i(Utils.TAG, "Comment id is " + commentId);
                }
            });

            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried moving dialogFrament into it's own file or not declaring it static? Just curious if this helps, i've read others having the same issue.

Comment: I have thought about this, but haven't tried it. I have placed this class inside my adapter class because I am not going to use it anywhere else and declared it static to avoid it having a reference to the adapter class to avoid memory leaks but now I guess it could be the cause of this leak. Thank you for confirming this idea. I'll try it and post the result here. In addition, could you please provide some links to where you have seen others with similar issues?

Comment: Your problem is likely due to the fact that you're using `setRetainInstance(true)`, which shouldn't generally be used for Fragments that present a UI (due to the easy possibility of memory leaks). I'm not sure what *exactly* is causing the memory leak in this instance, but I imagine if you turn off retain instance, you'll see the problem go away.

Comment: It has notging to do with retaining the instance because it is not retained if the fragment is destroyed (like pressing a back button). And what are you saying that it shouldn't be used with fragments that have UI? Man, it is desgined to be used exactly for this purpose - to retain it's instance across recreation of the UI, like screen rotation. By the way, I have already tried removing this line but it made absolutely no effect.

Comment: @reidisaki Bad news... I have just tested moving my dialog class to its own file but it didn't solve the issue...

Comment: @Salivan No, it's primarily designed for headless fragments that just retain some state or some long-running processes without worrying about it being destroyed on a configuration change. You *can* use it with UI, you just have to be very careful not to keep any View/Activity/etc. references around after onDestroyView()/onDetach()/etc. otherwise it's very easy to run into memory leaks. You also can't use setRetainInstance in combination with a backstack.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I saw this issue, but I keep notes on "gotchas" and this was one of them that might take a long time to debug.

**Putting the dialogFragment in it's own class or declaring it not static should fix the memory leak.**

Sorry I couldnt' give links but try it out and let others know this solution helped or not.

EDIT:

```
public static class FlagDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        private String commentId;
        private String number;
        private View testView;
```

and inside your onCreateView

```
testView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_flag_dialog, container, false);
```

then on onDestroyView()

```
   testView = null;
```

let me know how this works?

Comment: But shouldn't declaring this class static help to avoid memory leaks? And even developer.android.com recommends using static `Fragment` and other nested classes. However, I'll definitely try it out. This is a serious advice. Thanks.

Comment: Bad news... I have just tested moving my dialog class to its own file but it didn't solve the issue...